# Function Timeout API for Python

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout

I am trying to implement a function that will timeout if it fails to complete in a certain amount of time (having issues with a thread hanging). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821695) seemed the most promising, effectively providing an API wrapper with which to call my actual function. It generally seems to work (see loop_forever), but fails to stop when I use `time.sleep`. Why does the timeout not work with the sleep timer and will this work as a way to prevent threads from hanging?

```
import signal
import time

def timeout(func, args=(), kwargs={}, timeout_duration=1, default=None):


    class TimeoutError(Exception):
        pass

    def handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError()

    # set the timeout handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler) 
    signal.alarm(timeout_duration)
    try:
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    except TimeoutError as exc:
        result = default
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)

    return result




def loop_forever():
    x = 0
    while True:
        print x
        try:
            x += 1
        except:
            continue

def loop_forever_sleep():
    x = 0
    while True:
        print x
        try:
            x += 1
            time.sleep(10)
        except:
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = timeout(loop_forever) #Terminates
    b = timeout(loop_forever_sleep) #Does not terminate
```

Comment: What platforms are you targeting?

Comment: This is on Linux, I understand this function will not work on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `SIGALRM` is being raised while you're inside of the `time.sleep(10)` system call, which causes your `handler` to be called in that context, too. However, you're swallowing all the exceptions that happen inside of your infinite loop, so the `TimeoutError` never makes it back to the `timeout` function, instead it gets ignored by the `except: continue` code inside of `loop_forever_sleep`. Just remove the `try`/`except` block from the `while True` loop and it will work fine:

```
def loop_forever_sleep():
    x = 0
    while True:
        print x
        x += 1
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: So that means that anytime the timout occurs in a try block it will not get back to the API, just end that try block?

Comment: @Michael If you use bare `except` blocks, which will trap the `TimeoutError`, yes. You'll need to either only catch the specific exceptions you're expecting in your `try` blocks, or always re-raise `TimeoutError` if you catch it.